# Java: Appendable byte array

Tags: java, byte, arrays

I  want to append bytes to an byte array.
The result should be type `byte[]`, with adding single `byte`'s after calculating them, to it. 
So my question is:
What is the best and/or efficient way to accomplish that?
How to write to that?

Comment: I found the following link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368704/appending-a-byte-to-the-end-of-another-byte

thought it could help.

Comment: Do you know how many bytes?

Comment: the number of bytes may vary and is unknown at initialisation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ByteArrayOutputStream. This has a toByteArray() method when you are done

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using of Guava's ByteSource

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/ByteSource.html

It is much more efficient because of using a chains of small chunks inside instead of reallocating memory for a huge array (as ByteArrayOutputStream does).

Here is an example:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; 

List<ByteSource> loaded = new ArrayList<ByteSource>();

    while (true) {
        int read = input.read(buffer);
        if (read == -1) break;
        loaded.add(ByteSource.wrap(Arrays.copyOf(buffer, read)));
    }

ByteSource result = ByteSource.concat(loaded)
```